# Eclipse code formatter: Perform a single action

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

How can I perform a single action in Eclipse Java code formatter? For example I want to clean up every occurrence of

```
if (bla) {
...
}
else {
...
}
```

To this

```
if (bla) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

But nothing else. I need this to clean up specific findbugs issues. If I'd run the whole code formatter actions on the project, it would lead us into merge hell. So I want to handle such findbugs issues one by one and therefore It would be great to just execute such a single rule. The Version of Eclipse wouldn't matter, right now I tried with the latest Luna.

Comment: An alternate approach would be to find and replace using regex.

Comment: What is the "merge hell"? Is it because of wrapping lines and joining them? You can edit the formatted to never join wrapped lines and many other things

Comment: The merge hell would be touching/changing too many lines at too many files at the same time. And merging open branches back to a base branch were thousands and thousands of changes took place may be a bad Idea.

Comment: @epic_antihero: You could perform the formatting merge as one merge with no other changes to the source.  Tag the merge as the merge hell if you want. :-)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That's an option. But that's only possible if the uncommited changes present in the workspace can be discarded ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to do this would be to use the search and replace option in eclipse. Go to `Search menu->File`

Search for : `\}\s+\n\s+else\s+\{`

Replace with : `} else {`